# Odd Circumstances lost my whole xcode project from github

Tags: xcode, git, github

I write this with a heavy heart,

Another programmer started a project on my computer.  Unbeknownst to me they had set up a git repo for it but had never worked with it much before, had never pushed or synced any of the data.

I put in a few weeks work on the project, try to crank it out and assume it is being saved to my hard-drive.  I come back and all the files are reverted to when I originally received it from the other programmer.  Call up other programmer. Other programmer informs me he deleted the repo to start fresh on his git hub. I'm guessing those files were never saved to my hard drive but have been lost with the Git hub delete?   Any ideas || solutions || suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at http://think-like-a-git.net/halp.html

Answer (score 3):

Your project is stored locally deleting the github repository doesn't affect it.

Use `git log` to see if there is any commit you can go back to. If there is one you can use `git checkout <commit>` to switch to that state.

Also you can check if the code is on a other branch. To list the branches use  `git branch` then switch to it with `git checkout <branch>`

You can also try to use `git stash list` and see if there is any dirty working directory you can restore it with `git stash apply <stash>`

Comment: The git log command simply stated there was one commit when it originally happened.  I even asked Github and they were nice enough to recover the github account but there still seems to be no trace of the original.  Honestly, if I couldn't see some of the files by using finder-retrieve in a text doc, I would have thought I lost my mind.  Still missing alot of custom code files I built even with the finder command :/